# Create live USB that hides IP address from foreign government

Tags: privacy, usb-drive

I may have to visit family in a few months overseas. Unfortunately, the local government of the area my family is from has gotten more corrupt and vicious. I am compelled to go here and may need to use Internet while I am with my family, and I heard of creating live USB.

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB

Unfortunately, I cannot find how to create live USB that will protect my identity (hide my IP address, location, etc) once I am in that foreign country. I know it can be done, but I am unable to find these resource on the Internet now.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) is a project that provides exactly what you need, ready to download and install on  a USB flash drive.

Be warned that it is difficult to hide the fact that you are using Tor in the first place, which may raise suspicion in and of itself. My advice is to be careful where you use it. Depending on the country you could get your relatives in trouble if you use it at their house.

Answer (score 3):

All you should have to do is run TOR  https://www.torproject.org/  tor has downsides (mostly that it's slow / not terribly reliable) but should do the job and is free.  It should be easy to get working with most distributions.

The better solution would be VPN options.  If you google how to do that for your chosen distribution these can be better but you'll have to set up your connection in your home country to take your remote connection, or you'll have to use a vpn proxy service somewhere which you'll likely have to pay for.

It can be hard to identify if VPN services are legitimate; rumour and speculation is that many of them are using botnets as the proxying-backend.

Comment: When $government wants to control its populations internet usage, they will likely block all larger VPN services. Glowie should check which can be used from the country he wants to visit before subscribing to them.

Comment: In regards to TOR, it comes in Live USB flavor already, with the "TAILS" distro.

Comment: Yeah; tails is a good solution. I think a few others have it too.  I think it's funny that user267* nicked your suggestion as the winning answer!

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with Tor. It doesn't hide the fact that you are using it, they can see when you use it very easily, and they thus know you've something to hide from them, which can be somewhat dangerous with some governments. 
The best i would advise is ssh tunneling over an SSl tunnel (and tor at the end point if you want to be overkill). Correct me if i'm wrong, but i think it's less obvious to detect than Tor if you are not specifically looking for SSH over SSL.

Now if the government does DPI, they will sooner or later detect it and probably blacklist your server (or worse).